# MS-Access: Force error checking before leaving a form page

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm using MS-Access 2013 to develop a computer-aided personal interview form. Given the length of the interview it seemed to make the most sense to use multiple pages (tabs) within a form to aid user navigation. The problem with that is that the data error checking (either out of range checking, or missing entry checking) doesn't take place until you try to close the form (which might mean that an error on page 1 won't be "flagged" until (e.g.) page 10. Is there some way to "force" Access to do error checking on the fields on a given page before allowing the user to proceed to the next page?

Answer (score 0):

Hook the [Unload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845441(v=office.15).aspx) event of the form, and call your validation routine there.

If you need to validate between tabs, hook the [Tab.Change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835955(v=office.15).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use The Before Update Event of each field to validate that field before changes are written. Record The Previous Tab And Next Tab With the On Click Event. Test for missing fields before setting next tab to previous tab as skipped fields will not fire the before update validataion.